# Read data from Java and show it in Flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, interaction

well i am a little confused about the use of Flex and java, this is my problem: My java application must read two .zip files from an online server. These classes will load and parse the data in a Thread and perform certain actions depending on such info. The problem occurs when my flex application calls the java method that queries such data. I need to WAIT until the loading has finished. Any ideas?
Another doubt is if the Java classes are being compiled and transformed into some form of ActionScript classes.
Maybe I'm lost in space, so please I need a light in the darkness, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is either set up a remote object or httpservices so you can call a server side java method -> do what ever processing it needs to  -> and send a response to the flex application.  You should check out [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/) and [HttpServices](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_2.html).

Comment: I forgot to mention. You'll add result handler on the flex side to catch the java result.